# Ansbile AWS Dynamic Inventory Groups Fail to Match Play Hosts

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm having trouble getting my Ansible play's `hosts` to match the AWS dynamic groups that are coming back for my dynamic inventory. Let's break this problem down.

Given this output of `ec2.py --list`:

```
$ ./devops/inventories/dynamic/ec2.py  --list
{
  "_meta": {
    "hostvars": {
      "54.37.213.132": {
        "ec2__in_monitoring_element": false, 
        "ec2_ami_launch_index": "0", 
        "ec2_architecture": "x86_64", 
        "ec2_client_token": "", 
        "ec2_dns_name": "ec2-52-37-203-132.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", 
        "ec2_ebs_optimized": false, 
        "ec2_eventsSet": "", 
        "ec2_group_name": "", 
        "ec2_hypervisor": "xen", 
        "ec2_id": "i-d352c50b", 
        "ec2_image_id": "ami-63b25203", 
        "ec2_instance_profile": "", 
        "ec2_instance_type": "t2.micro", 
        "ec2_ip_address": "54.37.213.132", 
        "ec2_item": "", 
        "ec2_kernel": "", 
        "ec2_key_name": "peaker-v1-keypair", 
        "ec2_launch_time": "2016-03-11T20:45:44.000Z", 
        "ec2_monitored": false, 
        "ec2_monitoring": "", 
        "ec2_monitoring_state": "disabled", 
        "ec2_persistent": false, 
        "ec2_placement": "us-west-2a", 
        "ec2_platform": "", 
        "ec2_previous_state": "", 
        "ec2_previous_state_code": 0, 
        "ec2_private_dns_name": "ip-172-31-43-132.us-west-2.compute.internal", 
        "ec2_private_ip_address": "172.31.43.132", 
        "ec2_public_dns_name": "ec2-52-37-203-132.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com", 
        "ec2_ramdisk": "", 
        "ec2_reason": "", 
        "ec2_region": "us-west-2", 
        "ec2_requester_id": "", 
        "ec2_root_device_name": "/dev/xvda", 
        "ec2_root_device_type": "ebs", 
        "ec2_security_group_ids": "sg-824ac0e5", 
        "ec2_security_group_names": "peaker-v1-security-group", 
        "ec2_sourceDestCheck": "true", 
        "ec2_spot_instance_request_id": "", 
        "ec2_state": "running", 
        "ec2_state_code": 16, 
        "ec2_state_reason": "", 
        "ec2_subnet_id": "subnet-b96e1bce", 
        "ec2_tag_Environment": "v1", 
        "ec2_tag_Name": "peaker-v1-ec2", 
        "ec2_virtualization_type": "hvm", 
        "ec2_vpc_id": "vpc-5fe8ae3a"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "ec2": [
    "54.37.213.132"
  ], 
  "tag_Environment_v1": [
    "54.37.213.132"
  ], 
  "tag_Name_peaker-v1-ec2": [
    "54.37.213.132"
  ], 
  "us-west-2": [
    "54.37.213.132"
  ]
}
```

I should be able write a playbook that matches some of the groups coming back:

```
---
# playbook
- name: create s3 bucket with policy
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: s3
      s3:
        bucket: "fake"
        region: "us-west-2"
        mode: create
        permission: "public-read-write"
      register: s3_output
    - debug: msg="{{ s3_output }}"

- name: test on remote machine
  hosts: ec2
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: test on remote machine
      file:
        dest: "/home/ec2-user/test/"
        owner: ec2-user
        group: ec2-user
        mode: 0700
        state: directory
      become: yes
      become_user: ec2-user
```

However, when I `--list-hosts` that match these plays it's obvious that the play hosts are not matching anything coming back:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i devops/inventories/dynamic/ec2/ec2.py  devops/build_and_bundle_example.yml --ask-vault-pass --list-hosts
Vault password:
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available

playbook: devops/build_and_bundle_example.yml

  play #1 (localhost): create s3 bucket with policy TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'localhost']
    hosts (1):
      localhost

  play #2 (ec2): test on remote machine TAGS: []
    pattern: [u'ec2']
    hosts (0):
```

Comment: The paths to your ec2.py scripts are different between where you show the output of the dynamic inventory script and the playbook run.  Are you sure you're using the correct ec2.py script?

Comment: hosts: localhost ?

Comment: You connection are behind a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix for what you're doing:

- change `hosts: localhost` in your playbook to `hosts: all`

It would never work just with dynamic inventory if you're going to keep `hosts: localhost` in your playbook...

If so, – you must combine dynamic & static inventories. Create file with path `./devops/inventories/dynamic/static.ini` (on the same level with ec2.py and ec2.ini) and put this content:

```
[localhost]
localhost

[ec2_tag_Name_peaker_v1_ec2]

[aws-hosts:children]
localhost
ec2_tag_Name_peaker_v1_ec2
```

After that, you will be able to run a quick check:

```
ansible -i devops/inventories/dynamic/ec2 aws-hosts -m ping
```

and your playbook itself:

```
ansible-playbook -i devops/inventories/dynamic/ec2 \
    devops/build_and_bundle_example.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

*NOTE:* `devops/inventories/dynamic/ec2` is a path to the folder, but it will be automatically resolved into hybrid dynamic&static inventory with access to `aws-hosts` group name.

In fact, this isn't the best use of inventory. But it's important to understand, that by combining dynamic&static inventories, you're just appending new group names for particular dynamic host

```
ansible -i devops/inventories/dynamic/ec2 all -m debug \
    -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname].group_names"
```